# Can I disable SMS ID?

Tags: sms

I received a phishing text yesterday that purported to be from "NatwestUK". That in itself isn't entirely surprising; what bothered me was how easy it apparently is for any scam artist to use a service to disguise the number their text messages are being sent from. I want to know the number of anyone who contacts me; any system designed to hide this information seems thoroughly anti-consumer.

Is this something users have the ability to disable via software? Can my network (O2 UK) do it for me? Is it simply not possible in any manner due to how the system works?

Comment: That depends on the carrier , nothing in the OS to force revealing the numbers. If you are using Google dialler and SMS app, you can block such numbers. I find it quite effective

Comment: It's an LG G5 on rooted stock, so no dice there. Besides, I'm not looking to block the numbers because they're mostly legit. I just don't like knowing there's a facility for people to contact me directly without me knowing who they are.

Comment: AFAIK it is purely an arrangement between your carrier and the folks who send you these texts. Android per se has nothing to do with it and that makes it off topic here unfortunately

Comment: That's a shame. I did take a look around to see if there was a more generalised location to ask such a question. If you happen to know of one, please let me know.

Comment: I am at a loss to suggest where to ask. Let's hope for mods or better informed folks to suggest